# How to compress a mysql dump using 7z via a pipe?

Tags: command-line, mysql, dump, 7z

I've been attempting to compress my mysqldump output via 7z using the pipe operator (I have seen [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86570/how-to-use-7z-to-compress-via-pipe) question, but its answer uses xz not 7z). This is what I have tried so far:

```
mysqldump -u root -p Linux_Wiki | 7z > backup.sql.7z
```

and:

```
mysqldump -u root -p Linux_Wiki | 7za > backup.sql.7z
```

and:

```
mysqldump -u root -p Linux_Wiki | '7za a' > backup.sql.7z
```

and:

```
mysqldump -u root -p Linux_Wiki | `7za a` > backup.sql.7z
```

All four failed, but I am sure I have `p7zip` installed, after all the last of these attempts gave this output:

```
Enter password: bash: 7-Zip: command not found
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First store the password in a file called `.my.cnf` in the users home directory with the following format:

```
[mysqldump]
password=secret
```

---

Then, you have to use `mysqldump` without the `-p` flag to dump a mysql database (it now uses the password from the file):

```
mysqldump -u root database | 7z a -si backup.sql.7z
```

- The `a` flag of `7z` adds to the archive
- `-si` means to read from the standard input (from the anonymous pipe).

Comment: Sorry, rofl, I forgot the `dump` (I have edited my question accordingly), I did use `mysqldump` from the command-line though. Your code, when I substituted Linux_Wiki as my database I got the output: ```Enter password: 
7-Zip [64] 9.38 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2014 Igor Pavlov  2015-01-03
p7zip Version 9.38.1 (locale=en_AU.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs,ASM)

Error: backup.sql.7z is not supported archive


System error:
Operation not permitted

mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect```

Comment: I think you missed a `>` after `-si`. But even when I added the `>` I got the error: `Enter password: 
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write`

Comment: @BrentonHorne No, it is meant without a `>`. The error comes from the `mysqldump` command which cannot connect to the database: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`. The username or password is wrong.

Comment: It didn't give me a chance to provide my password. It just gave me that error, before I could even enter my password.

Comment: @BrentonHorne See my edit

Comment: By my 'home directory' do you mean `~/`? I log in using the mysql root account, so should I store it in `/root`?

Comment: @BrentonHorne yes `~/.my.cnf`. You can remove it after the operation.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still getting errors ```7-Zip [64] 9.38 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2014 Igor Pavlov  2015-01-03
p7zip Version 9.38.1 (locale=en_AU.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs,ASM)

Error: backup.sql.7z is not supported archive


System error:
Operation not permitted
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
```

Comment: @BrentonHorne The file `backup.sql.7z` still persists in the directory from previous attempts and is most probably empty; remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Some people may frown upon this practice, but you can put the password on the command line, like so:

```
mysqldump -u root -pmyrootpassword database | 7z a -si backup.sql.7z
```

It has to be placed immediately after the `-p` argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pipes with 7zip algorithm, you should consider using xz instead of 7z.

xz uses exactly the same algorithm as 7z but it can be used just like gzip (or bzip2). xz and 7zip were designed by the same author.

```
mysqldump -u root -p Linux_Wiki | xz -9 > backup.sql.xz
```

The GUI of 7zip understands xz.